# Updating variables values - Three.js in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, three.js

I'm having trouble with updating variables values in my Three.js Angular project. I have a simple click test function to change value of variables, I can see them changing in console, but nothing besides that. Also, value is not changed in setAnimationLoop function when I console.log that variable. I tried to change earthRadius and globalRotationSpeed. Using translateX on camera works tho. Here is a sample of the code:

```
export class ModelComponent implements OnInit {   
//Earth radius
earthRadius: number = 3;
globalRotationSpeed = 0.000001;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  this.cameraFov,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  3000
);

constructor() {
  const globalRotationSpeed = this.globalRotationSpeed;
  //Creating a renderer
  const renderer = this.renderer;
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const scene = this.scene;

  //Camera
  const camera = this.camera;
  camera.position.set(0, 360, 180);

  const orbit = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

  const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
    'assets/textures/stars-background.jpg',
    function (this: any) {
      renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
        //Earth animation
        earth.position.set(earthDistance, 0, 0);
        earth.rotateY(earthRotationSpeed * globalRotationSpeed);
        earthPivotPoint.rotateY(earthOrbitalSpeed * globalRotationSpeed);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);

      });
    }
  );
  const earthTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
    'assets/textures/earth-texture.jpg'

  //Creating Earth Mesh
  const earthGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(this.earthRadius, 30, 30);
  const earthMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    map: earthTexture,
  });
  const earth = new THREE.Mesh(earthGeometry, earthMaterial);
  //Creating Earth pivot point
  const earthPivotPoint = new THREE.Group();
  earthPivotPoint.rotateY(
    degToRad(AE.EclipticLongitude(AE.Body.Earth, date))
  );
  scene.add(earthPivotPoint);
  earthPivotPoint.add(earth);

  

}

ngOnInit(): void {}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  console.log(changes);
}

changeSpeed() //test onclick function {
  console.log(this.earthRadius); // result: 3
  this.earthRadius = 10; //does not work
  this.camera.translateX(10); //works
  console.log(this.earthRadius); // result: 10
}
```

So my final question is: what is the way to change the value of a variable so that can be used by the animation loop?

Comment: Better to create a sphere of radius 1, then use `.scale.setScalar( desired_radius );` on it, though the `sphere` has to be a property of a class, so you can refer to it with `this.sphere.scale...`

Comment: That's true, but unfortunately I'm gonna need to change other variables that can't be used like that